# Correct event to calculate Cells values in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In a DataGridView I use this code, in the `CellEndEdit` event to automatically calculate the amounts multiplied by the quantity:

```
private void myGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView oDGV = (DataGridView)sender; 
    DataGridViewCell oCell = oDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    // Only the quantity can be changed
    if (oCell.Value != DBNull.Value && oCell.OwningColumn.Name == "num")
    {
        oDGV.EndEdit(); 
        int nNum = Convert.ToInt16(oCell.Value);
        decimal nPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(oDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["price"].Value.ToString());
        decimal nTot = nPrice * nNum;
        oDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["tot"].Value = nTot;
    }
}
```

Apparently a simple operation, but it happens to me every so often that the calculation is not carried out and I have to go back to the cell, type the value again and press enter (even if everything is correct on the screen).
I don't understand where the problem is, maybe I have to use another event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 Columns that need to *interact*:

- `price` Column: it should specify a `Unit Price`
- `num` Column: it should be the number of Items, the `Quantity`
- `tot` Column: the `Total` value represented by `[Unit Price] * [Quantity]`

Since the third Column's (`Total`) Value is obtained multiplying the price (`Unit Price`) by the number (`Quantity`) of items, this calculation can transferred to a [DataTable.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression): this operation is fixed (it always refers to the same Columns, which always have the same Value Type).

```
DataTable.Columns["Total"].Expression = "[Unit Price] * [Quantity]";
```

In your code, of course, you use the names you have assigned to your Columns:

```
[Your DataTable].Columns["tot"].Expression = "[price] * [num]";
```

▶ Note that, since you are expressing a Price (currency), you probably want to use a Decimal type to represent that Value, not an integer type. The same applies to the `Total` Column.

The Expression can be assigned right after you have loaded the DataTable, or after you have assigned it to the `DataGridView.DataSource` property.
Assigning the property, the [DataSourceChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasourcechanged) event is raised:

```
private void myGrid_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myGrid.DataSource is DataTable dt && dt.Columns.IndexOf("tot") >= 0) {
        dt.Columns["tot"].Expression = "[num] * [price]";
    }
}
```

▶  The Cells don't need to contain a value, both `[Unit Price]` and `[Quantity]` can be `null`, no exception is thrown. You can of course use the DataGridView `NewRow` to add a new Row to the DataTable.

To change the value of the `Total` Column right after either the `Unit Price` or the `Quantity` values are changed, subscribe to the **`CellEndEdit`** or **`CellValueChanged`** events and Validate the edit. In this case, you don't need to press Enter or change Row to see the new calculated value appear, just move the cursor to another adjacent Cell (Excel style).

```
private void myGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) => Validate();
```