# inquiry Data from data table to datagridview with filters

Tags: vb.net, datatables

i have datatable "dataitems" contain 98000 Rows And Datagridview have 11000 row

want to add the quantity form the datatable to the datagridview every item in it's row in the datagrid view

i am using this code but its take too too too much time to run and sometimes stop responding i need ideas to make it faster to run

```
Dim dt As New DataTable = najrndataset.dataitems

Dim Total As Integer    

for x = 0 to datagridview1.rows.count -1
Dim b = datagridview1.rows(x).cells(1)
Dim c = 3
Total = (From r As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
             Where r.Field(Of String)("Item_Number") = b And r.Field(Of Integer)("SOP_Type") = c
             Select r.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity")).Sum
    datagridview1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = Total
next
```

Comment: You could use a calculated Column (a Column that uses an Expression), as shown here: [Correct event to calculate Cells values in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62291110/7444103) or use the `CellFormatting` (or `CellValueChanged`) event of your DGV. Or do that in a query. -- Assuming `najrndataset.dataitems` also sets the DataSource of your DGV. In that case, why are you replicating it here, to set Cells value directly (with all the events that this operation raises, repainting included)? What is the DataSource of your DGV?

Comment: If `Datagridview1` has 11,000 rows, then the loop will run 11,000 times. Each loop iteration will assign `Total` **to the same place**. So the first 10,999 loop iterations _don't matter_, because the 11,000th last time through the loop will _overwrite the work_ from the previous iterations. **That can't be right.** Unfortunately, I can't help you much until it's clearer what the loop is actually supposed to do.

Comment: i have datatable contain 98000 rows every row have column for the quantity and the sop_type and the item number and i have datagridview contain 11000 rows every row have column for the item number i need to sum the quantity of every item in the datatable and copy the summation to the datagridview in the item row  so the loop suppose to check every row in the datatable 11000 times to find the datagridview row which have the same item number

Comment: i want to make summation of the column[Quantity] in the datatble with 2 filters item_no and Sop_type and copy the summation to the datagridview in the row which have the same item_no

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn not in the same place it was mistake and i edited the code

Comment: Okay. This also uses `datagridview1` in one place, and `DGV1` in another. Is that a typo? As those two items the same thing?

Comment: the datable rows is invoices and the datagridview is the items list , so in need the code to sum the quantity of the item in the datatable  and seacrch the datagridview to find the  index of the row of this item in the datagridview and add the quantity to it @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: it was also a mistake and i edited it @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: *Datagridview have 11000 row* - well I bet that UI is a delight to use :/

Comment: Seems you're using a typed dataset; quite why you'd assign one of its tables to an untyped dataset and then try to work with it via LINQ, I'm really not sure.. Unless you like to make your life as painful as possible

Comment: @HussienGouda I was an accountant for most of my career but switched to programming late in life. Be careful! You might switch too. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you appreciate that if you have 11000 rows in a datagridview (terrible idea, by the way) and 98000 rows in a datatable, and you're running a loop that searches the table for each of the 11K items, and it does this by starting at number 1, and searching 98000 items for it, then going to 2 and searching 98000 items for it til you reach 11000 and searching 98000 items for it... At the end of the operation you're going to have performed 11000 x 98000 operations.. i.e. you're going to have performed **1.078 BILLION** operations. This is why "its take too too too much time to run and sometimes stop responding" :)

You can speed this up by using a dictionary to track the sums, and it'll probably be fastest to index the 98000 items then set the dictionary from them:

```
Dim d as New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each di In najrndataset.dataitems.Where(Function(r) r.SOP_Type = 3)
  If Not d.ContainsKey(di.Item_Number) Then 
    d(di.Item_Number) = di.Quantity
  Else
    d(di.Item_Number) += di.Quantity
  End If
Next di
```

Then edit your grid (ugh; this isn't how datagridview are supposed to be used)

```
datagridview1.SuspendDrawing()


For x = 0 to datagridview1.rows.count - 1
  Dim b = datagridview1.rows(x).cells(1)
  Dim s As Integer
  If d.TryGetValue(b, s) Then
    datagridview1.rows(x).cells(0) = s
  End If
Next x

datagridview1.ResumeDrawing()
```

You could also have a logic of "loop over the datagrid, putting 11000 items in the dictionary, loop over the datatable accumulating sums into the dictionary if the keys are present in the dictionary, loop over the datagriview putting the sums into the datagridview".

Comment: I am so so so thankful to you, your code is working very good , and i want to let you know that i am not programmer I am accountant only try to learn some vb.net basics to help me in my accounting work by devolpe some simple forms to inquiry data from sql server database , thaks so much again for you help

Comment: the Item_Number column in the datatable have spaces after the item number how can i remove these spaces ? for example "I-711152-4-TT.................." ineed to remove these spaces in the dictionary not in the datatable

Comment: Above `If Not d.ContainsKey`, put `Dim trimmedItemNumber = r.Item_Number.TrimEnd()`, then use `trimmedItemNumber ` instead of `r.Item_Number` in the rest of the loop

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, but too long for a traditional comment. I'm working to provide an answer separately.*

---

I can't tell you how many times I've seen code like this:

```
Dim someVariable As New SomeObject
someVariable = someMethodToReturnSomeObject()
```

**This pattern is bad code!**

The `New` operator in the first line tells the compiler you want to allocate memory and run the constructor for your type. However, the next line assigns a new object... it throws away and forgets the memory and constructor work from the previous line. That's wasteful.

Instead, you want this:

```
Dim someVariable As SomeObject = someMethodToReturnSomeObject()
```

Worse, this speaks to a profound lack of understanding of the difference between a reference and an object, and what the computer is doing with your code in memory. This is a *core principle* of how many programming environments work. Code like the first example gives me big doubts of the capability of the programmer who writes it.

Comment: thanks for your advice , i edited the code i will be thankful if you help me in my code